# Laravel: Missing font at export to PDF?

Tags: laravel, fonts, dompdf

I am exporting a blade view to PDF but something is wrong...
That´s the error:

```
ErrorException (E_WARNING)
fopen(/Users/marcellopato/Sites/primorossi/storage/fonts//aa43f2bf57704d041dfc34a504551bc2.ufm): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Looks like a font is missing... is that right? How do I fix it?

Comment: do you have a folder `fonts` in the `storage` folder? and i guess you are using laravel-dompdf?

Comment: Yes, I am using 'barryvdh/laravel-dompdf' and no, there isn't a folder called fonts. I will try to reinstall

Comment: you have to make that folder and make sure the webserver has permissions to write to it

Comment: But it is not required at the installation... right?

Comment: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/blob/master/config/dompdf.php#L20   i am just going off what the configuration says

Comment: Worked... but the look is terrible. I think now is a matter of CSS.
Thank You!

Comment: np, good luck with your project ... you can put up your own answer to this so that this isn't an unanswered question

Answer (score 0):

your must to make dir  storage/fonts
in root dir